# Elasticsearch with Java, how to access elements of a multi value field with Java API

Tags: java, arraylist, elasticsearch

I have done lots of Googling with this but no luck. Basically I have a field on my document that contains lots of different IDs, I want to go through each one and store it into an ArrayList.

Can this be done / is there an easier way if doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to cast it. You extract the `SearchHitField` instance for that field, and then cast to a collection. It should look something like this, for a multi-field of integer IDs:

```
SearchHitField field = searchHit.getFields().get(fieldName);
List<Integer> value = (List<Integer>) field.getValue();
```

Comment: I'm guessing that searchHit is an array of the hits? When I try and access the getFields() method it doesn't seem to exists. This is what I tried, but I keep getting runtime errors saying ArrayList cannot be cast to SearchField. `SearchHitField messageIdField = (SearchHitField) hit.get("message_ids");
        List<Object> messageIds = messageIdField.getValues();`